# Mail Session fails in Tomee Server

Tags: java, tomee-8

I can send an email via a simple Java programme but if I use exactly the same settings to create Java Mail Session resource in Tomee's conf/tomee.xml file, the code fails:

Here is the simple Java code that WORKS:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        // smtp.gmail.com supports TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3
        // smtp.office365.com supports only TLSv1.2
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.privateemail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("<valid email>", "<valid password>");
            }
        });
        
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(<valid email>));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(<valid recipient email>));
            message.setSubject("You got mail");
            message.setText("This email was sent with JavaMail.");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Email sent.");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

However, if I try to configure the same properties in Tomee's conf/tomee.xml file, nothing works and the application throws an error:

```
Send failure (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: null)
```

Here is the configuration in conf/tomee.xml

```
<Resource id="mail/bjm" type="javax.mail.Session">
        mail.smtp.host=smtp.privateemail.com
        mail.smtp.port=587
        mail.transport.protocol=smtp
        mail.smtp.auth=true
        ail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
        mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2
        mail.smtp.user=<valid email>
        password=<valid password>
</Resource>
```

The configuration settings were copied from the Tomee docs that DOES NOT WORK.

And finally here is my Java/EE code that uses this resource in vain:

```
@Resource(name = "mail/bjm")
Session session;
...
...
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(<valid email>));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(<valid recipient email>));
```

Would be grateful if someone can shed some light on the issue.

Many Thanks

Comment: apache-tomee-8.0.13-plume with JDK 8

Comment: Have you looked at the mail example provided by TomEE: https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/tomee-8.x/examples/javamail-velocity ? It might be related to the SSL/TLS version used by your mail server, so might also be relevant to enable and check the tls/ssl debug output.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for providing this link. However, I regret to say that the example code has got an issue. Could not find the given email template 'templates/email-html-template.vm' in the classpath.. The file is not there in github. Please advice.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/tomee-8.x/examples/javamail-velocity/src/test/resources/templates/email-html-template.vm